# Error: The proposed data changes would violate a uniqueness constraint when changing a format page of an approval process

Tags: page-layout, approval-process

I already had created an approval process for the "quotes" object and it was working fine. The client asked us to add a custom field to the page layout of this approval process. This is a formula field that returns a currency (subtotal - totalPrice). So in the approval process I go to the "page layout" section and add the custom field. There it marks an error.

I tried to create another field x (text type) and then another (number type) and it still sends the same error.

Finally, I just opened the page layout editor and saved it (without having modified anything) and it sent me the same error again. So I realized that it was not really the fault of the field I was adding but something that was already previously in that approval process.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). What further investigation have you completed and what are you actually asking the community to help you with? Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to simply change this.: [image]